# Ruby: Trying to better understand the use of Hash#delete

Tags: ruby, hash

I have seen a lot of examples of Ruby classes that utilize the `Hash` method of `delete` and I am not sure what the advantage of using it would be.

Example:

```
class Example
  def initialize(default_params = {})
    @foo = default_params.delete(:bar)
  end
end
```

Any insight would be extremely helpful! Thanks!

Comment: They really, really shouldn't be. They're modifying an object they shouldn't be modifying, if they're doing what you're code does. If they're `dup`-ing their params first, that's different.

Comment: This is the code example I was looking at: https://github.com/amro/gibbon/blob/master/lib/gibbon/api.rb

Comment: That is a poorly behaving library. He wants to extract several keys and pass the rest through to some API, but he's quite inappropriately modifying the hash that is being passed in.

Comment: @meagar - gotcha, can you explain the better use-case for `Hash#delete`?

Comment: It's for when you want to remove a key/value from a hash. There are a million reasons why you might want to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hash#delete` is useful in the following situation:

```
def method(options)
  if options.delete(:condition)
    # Do something if options[:condition] is true
  else
    # Otherwise do something else
  end

  # Now options doesn't have the :conditions key-value pair.
  another_method_that_doesnt_use_the_condition(options)
end
```

I'm unsure if the specific example you pulled should be using `Hash#delete`.